# CPU for Polkadot validator

Tags: blockchain, intel, hardware, polkadot

I want to build **validator node** for staking in Polkadot. In hardware requirements specified 7700k. Is it possible to set up Intel Xeon **E5-2650 v2** instead of Intel Core **7700k**

Recommended configuration: https://wiki.polkadot.network/ru-RU/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot

My thoughts: if node support multithreading difference between i7 and Xeon insignificant

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming, it's asking for a hardware recommendation for existing software.  https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be relevant to compare that old Xeon with a modern Kaby Lake.

Comment: The weights are calculated for the 7700k. If you use different hardware it is possible that the weights are higher than anticipated. This is basically your own risk. You could also re-run the benchmarks for your hardware to be sure.